# Sending JSON object back to server through YUI IO utility?

Tags: javascript, python, django, yui

I am running a web page that generates random data and displays it in a HTML table. From the table I run a loop to gather the basic information (all rows that exist and exclude headers of table). This data gets stored in a JSON object called jData.

I want to send this data back to the server and store in a sqlite table named data. The way I am trying to do this is therough the YUI IO utility.

I am trying to wade the API documentation, but I am having no luck. I have two buttons on the page. One to generate the data and on to store the data. The store code is as follows:

```
var savedata = function(){
    var tabledata = Y.one("#generatedtable")._node;
    var jData = [];
    var i = 1;
    var length = tabledata.rows.length
    while (i<length){
        var samplerow = {};
        var r = tabledata.rows[i];
        samplerow.timestamp = r.cells[0].innerHTML;
        samplerow.volts = r.cells[1].innerHTML;
        samplerow.amps = r.cells[2].innerHTML;
        samplerow.kW = r.cells[3].innerHTML;
        samplerow.kWh = r.cells[4].innerHTML;
        jData.push(samplerow);
        i++;
        }

Y.io("./savedata", Y.System_Config.postjData(jData));
};
```

Using the chrome debugger tools I see the array being stored properly into jData. I need some basic help with Y.io and how to make posts. Any basic help is much appreciated. My server is run bu the Django Python web application framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read the [IO User Guide](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/io/). Making a POST request with JSON data in YUI is as simple as setting the HTTP method to POST, adding the data and setting the `Content-Type` to `application/json`. The only caveat is that you need to turn the JSON object into a string first using `JSON.stringify()`.

```
Y.io('/savedata', {
  method: 'POST',
  data: Y.JSON.stringify(jData),
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  on: {
    success: function (id, response) {
      // do something with the response from the server, for example
      Y.one('#some-node').set('text', response.responseText);
    }
  }
});
```

You can read more about all the configuration options for IO in the ["Configuration Object"](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/io/#the-configuration-object) section of the User Guide. There is an example there of a POST request with JSON data.

Comment: How do I make the button call this Y.io function? What exactly is happening? Once I press the buttons does it call path/savedata in the url bar? Do I have to write this into my views? Sorry for asking all these seemingly basic questions.

Comment: Also could you elaborate on what is suppose to go next to success? What kind of function. Is this where I write the database interaction code?

Comment: This is all happening in the browser. You need to handle the database code in your server. AJAX makes a network request without reloading the page or changing the URL in the browser's navigation bar. I suggest you read about AJAX requests and how they work. Here's a nice introduction: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX. 

I updated the answer to be more clear on what the success function looks like.